# How to add an onclick event by creating a toggle button in tinymce editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I am trying to add a button to TinyMCE editor in wordpress.
here the code that register register button to wordpress that wordks fine:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wptuts_buttons' );
function wptuts_buttons() {
    add_filter( "mce_external_plugins", "wptuts_add_buttons" );
    add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'wptuts_register_buttons' );
}
function wptuts_add_buttons( $plugin_array ) {
    $plugin_array['wptuts'] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/webramz-tinymce-toggle.js';
    return $plugin_array;
}
function wptuts_register_buttons( $buttons ) {
    array_push( $buttons, 'mybutton' ); // dropcap', 'recentposts
    return $buttons;
}
```

and here the js plugin code to add button and it's command:

```
(function() {
    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.Wptuts', {
        init : function(ed, url) {
           ed.addButton('mybutton', {
                text: "rtl-ltr",
                cmd : 'mybuttoncmd',
            });
            ed.addCommand('mybuttoncmd', function() {
                //function () {
                    $(".wp-editor-area").addClass("ltr");
                //}
            });
        },
        // ... Hidden code
    });
    // Register plugin
    tinymce.PluginManager.add( 'wptuts', tinymce.plugins.Wptuts );
})();
```

button is appear but have this errors in console when clicked:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
```

what is my fault?
in fact I want to add a toggle button to add and remove "ltr" class to "textarea" in "text mode".
any help? thank you.

Comment: Have you included a reference to the jquery library?

Comment: I am not sure understood your question

Comment: See Michael's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While WordPress loads jQuery it loads it in a somewhat different way than if you load jQuery in a regular app - it uses "compatibility mode".

The net of what it does is that `$` is not defined but `jQuery` is defined.  So when you use `$` to try to run jQuery its not defined.  If you change that to use `jQuery`:

```
jQuery(".wp-editor-area").addClass("ltr");
```

...I would suspect things would start working for you.

For a good explanation you can read this post:  https://digwp.com/2011/09/using-instead-of-jquery-in-wordpress/

Comment: Thank You Very Much! It Works Like A Charm.

Comment: Do you have any idea about: how to add button to editor in text mode instead of visual mode in wordpress?

Comment: The text mode does not use TinyMCE at all so I can't help you with that part.